# If statement inside an if statement c#

Tags: c#

I have written a console application to print when a user enters a number. When a user press 1, the console prints the text specified in the corresponding `if` statement. How do I get this working?

```
int keypress; // Variable to hold number

ConsoleKeyInfo UserInput = Console.ReadKey(); // Get user input

// We check input for a Digit
if (char.IsDigit(UserInput.KeyChar))
{
    keypress = int.Parse(UserInput.KeyChar.ToString()); // use Parse if it's a Digit

    if (keypress = 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("6$ Cheese added to your cart");

    }
    else (keypress = 2){

        Console.WriteLine("2$ Bread added to your cart");
    }
     else (keypress = 3){

        Console.WriteLine("1$ cookie added to your cart");
    }

}

else
{
    keypress = -1;  // Else we assign a default value
    Console.WriteLine("Number you entered isn't in the grocery list, please retry");
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is your exception?

Comment: "if (keypress = 1)"   Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

Comment: You don't use equal operator, use ==. With single = you're assigning a value to a variable

Comment: `=` is used to assign value but `==` is used to compare.

Comment: You're trying to do an assignment when you mean to do a comparison (`==`).

Comment: except `==` you need to use `else if `

Comment: This might not be the best approach.  What if your list goes past 9 items? You should consider using `Console.ReadLine()` instead.

Answer (score 8):

You use assignment operator `=` instead of `==`. So change `=` with `==` in your if conditions.

Also you need to add new `if` after `else` because you have new condition,
your code will look like this:

```
int keypress; // Variable to hold number

ConsoleKeyInfo UserInput = Console.ReadKey(); // Get user input

// We check input for a Digit
if (char.IsDigit(UserInput.KeyChar))
{
     keypress = int.Parse(UserInput.KeyChar.ToString()); // use Parse if it's a Digit

     if (keypress == 1)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("6$ Cheese added to your cart");
     }
     else if (keypress == 2)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("2$ Bread added to your cart");
     }
     else if (keypress == 3)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("1$ cookie added to your cart");
     }
 }
 else
 {
      keypress = -1;  // Else we assign a default value
      Console.WriteLine("Number you entered isn't in the grocery list, please retry");
 }
```

You can also use `switch` to achieve the same.

```
if (char.IsDigit(UserInput.KeyChar))
{
    keypress = int.Parse(UserInput.KeyChar.ToString()); // use Parse if it's a Digit

    switch (keypress)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("6$ Cheese added to your cart");
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("2$ Bread added to your cart");
            break;
        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine("1$ cookie added to your cart");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
else
{
    keypress = -1;  // Else we assign a default value
    Console.WriteLine("Number you entered isn't in the grocery list, please retry");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "IF" use "elseIF", use "if(keypress == 1)" instead of "if(keypress = 1)" but a better way would be a "switch case" look at the example below:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo UserInput = Console.ReadKey(); // Get user input

            // We check input for a Digit
            if (char.IsDigit(UserInput.KeyChar))
            {
                keypress = int.Parse(UserInput.KeyChar.ToString()); // use Parse if it's a Digit

                switch(keypress)
           {
                case = 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("6$ Cheese added to your cart");
                break;
                case = 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("2$ Bread added to your cart");
                break;
                case = 3:
                break;
                    Console.WriteLine("1$ cookie added to your cart");

                default:

                keypress = -1;  // Else we assign a default value
                Console.WriteLine("Number you entered isn't in the grocery list, please retry");
                break;
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

`=` is an assignment operator.
`==` is an equality operator.

You need to use `==` when using conditional statements.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the assignment operator '=' instead of the equality operator '=='.

```
keypress = 1;
```

The above will try to assign keypress to a value of 1.

```
keypress == 1;
```

The above code will evaluate if keypress is equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

A few things here:

```
// As others have indicated, this should be "=="
// Or, even better, convert this whole thing to a "switch" statement
if (keypress = 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("6$ Cheese added to your cart");

}
// Should be "else if"
else (keypress = 2){

    Console.WriteLine("2$ Bread added to your cart");
}
// Should also be "else if"
 else (keypress = 3){

    Console.WriteLine("1$ cookie added to your cart");
}
```